# MySQL where STR_TO_DATE >= now

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

I want to get records from the MySQL database with date today or later. The data is recorded into the database as VARCHAR (fieldname datum), so I need to use STR_TO_DATE. However, this query is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM Diensten WHERE STR_TO_DATE('datum', '%m-%d-%Y') >= DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE('datum', '%m-%d-%Y') ASC
```

I also tried CURDATE(), doesn't work either.

The query is working without the WHERE part. Any ideas how to fix the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression `STR_TO_DATE('datum', '%m-%d-%Y')` returns `NULL` because the column name was quoted using single quote. It doesn't convert the `value` of column `datum` but string `datum` is converted that is why it results to a `NULL` value.

To fix, just remove the single quotes around the column name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Diensten 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d-%m-%Y') >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(datum, '%d-%m-%Y') ASC
```

- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: followup question, why are you storing dates as string in the database?

Comment: Thank you. This is resulting in one record shown, but there are 4:

21-07-2013
23-07-2013
02-08-2013
12-08-2013

I only see 12-08-2013 now

Comment: it should be `'%d-%m-%Y'` not `'%m-%d-%Y'`. the other three results to `NULL` because month is only upto `12`.

Comment: Stupid :( Thank you very much! The database is already in use, someone else designed it, that is the reason why dates are in there as string.